# Is scalability applicable with Kafka stream if each topic has single partition

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

My understanding as per Kafka stream documentation, 
Maximum possible parallel tasks is equal to maximum number of partitions of a topic among all topics in a cluster.

I have around 60 topics at Kafka cluster. Each topic has single partition only. 
Is it possible to achieve scalability/parallelism with Kafka stream for my Kafka cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to do the same computation over all topics? For this, I would recommend to introduce an extra topic with many partitions that you use to scale out:

```java
// using new 1.0 API
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder():
KStream parallelizedStream = builder
    .stream(/* subscribe to all topics at once*/)
    .through("topic-with-many-partitions");

// apply computation
parallelizedStream...
```

> Note: You need to create the topic "topic-with-many-partitions" manually before starting your Streams application

Pro Tip:

> The topic "topic-with-many-partitions" can have a very short retention time as it's only used for scaling and must not hold data long term.

**Update**

If you have 10 topic T1 to T10 with a single partitions each, the program from above will execute as follows (with TN being the dummy topic with 10 partitions):

```
T1-0  --+           +--> TN-0   --> T1_1
...   --+--> T0_0 --+--> ...    --> ...
T10-0 --+           +--> TN-10  --> T1_10
```

The first part of your program will only read all 10 input topics and write it back into 10 partitions of TN. Afterwards, you can get up to 10 parallel tasks, each processing one input partition. If you start 10 `KafakStreams` instances, only one will execute T0_0, and each will alsa one T1_x running.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve scalability without streaming all topic events to dummy topic? Please help.

Comment: Not easily. Advanced users could provide a custom partition assignor -- thus one must understand many internals about Kafka Streams to get this right. In general, Kafka Streams scale via the number of partitions, thus, you should use topics with many partitions to scale your application.

Comment: Would the order of events be maintained same as input topic in the output topic if the intermediate dummy topic is used. I have this concern since kafka doesn't maintain order across partitions.

Comment: @RednamNagendra That sounds correct. By default, it would maintain order per key, as all records with the same key will get piped through the same partition on the intermediate dummy topic. But across keys. Usually, order per-key is sufficient for most applications.

Comment: Is below scale applicable? I have one partition for each topic from Topic 1 to Topic 10 and I am running one application instance. In this case partitions '0' of  all topics would be processed by that single instance. Now I will create dummy topic with 10 partitions and Will run 10 application instances. In this case, are all ('partition '0' of Topic 1 to Topic 10) partitions scale across 10 instances? Or Instance 1 will consider partitions '0' of all topics,  Instance 2 will consider partition '1' of dummy topic.. instance 10 will consider partition '9' of dummy topic. In which way scale?

Comment: Extendedn my answer