# Kafka Stream Rebalancing : State transition from REBALANCING to ERROR

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have 4 topics with single partition and three instances of the application. I tried to achieve scalability by writing a custom PartitionGrouper which would create 3 tasks as below:

1st instance-topic1,partition0,topic4,partition0

2nd instance-topic2,partition0

3rd instance-topic3,partition0

I configured NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG to 1  since it would maintain states locally(also to eliminate invalidstatestore exception).

The above setup worked fine for two instances. When I increased it to three instances I started facing issues w.r.t rebalancing.

```
StickyTaskAssignor:58 - Unable to assign 1 of 1 standby tasks for task [1009710637_0]. There is not enough available capacity. You should increase the number of threads and/or application instances to maintain the requested number of standby replicas.
    [INFO ] 2017-12-25 20:05:42.221 [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] StreamThread:888 - stream-thread [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_REVOKED to PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED.
    [INFO ] 2017-12-25 20:05:42.221 [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] KafkaStreams:268 - stream-client [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449] State transition from REBALANCING to REBALANCING.
    [INFO ] 2017-12-25 20:05:42.276 [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] StreamThread:195 - stream-thread [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] partition assignment took 55 ms.
    current active tasks: [1009710637_0]
    current standby tasks: [1240464215_0, 1833680710_0]
    previous active tasks: []
    [INFO ] 2017-12-25 20:05:42.631 [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] StreamThread:939 - stream-thread [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] Shutting down
    [INFO ] 2017-12-25 20:05:42.631 [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] StreamThread:888 - stream-thread [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED to PENDING_SHUTDOWN.
    [INFO ] 2017-12-25 20:05:42.633 [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] KafkaProducer:972 - Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
    [INFO ] 2017-12-25 20:05:42.638 [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] StreamThread:972 - stream-thread [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] Stream thread shutdown complete
    [INFO ] 2017-12-25 20:05:42.638 [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] StreamThread:888 - stream-thread [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] State transition from PENDING_SHUTDOWN to DEAD.
    [WARN ] 2017-12-25 20:05:42.638 [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] KafkaStreams:343 - stream-client [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449] All stream threads have died. The Kafka Streams instance will be in an error state and should be closed.
    [INFO ] 2017-12-25 20:05:42.638 [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449-StreamThread-1] KafkaStreams:268 - stream-client [app-03-cfaf7841-dc19-4ee4-9d05-ae4928c21449] State transition from REBALANCING to ERROR.
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `PartitionGrouper` breaks something. It's it quite hard to write a correct custom partition grouper as you need to know a lot of internals about Kafka Streams. Thus, it is not recommended in the first place.

The error itself means, that a StandbyTask cannot be assigned to a thread successfully, as there are not enough threads. In general, the idea is that a StandbyTask cannot be assigned to a thread the runs the corresponding "active" task or a another copy of the same StandbyTasks: it does not increase fault-tolerance but only wastes memory as if a thread dies, all the task dies.

Why you get this error in particular is unclear (happy debugging :)).

> However, for your use case, you should just start different application instances subscribing to individual topics and using different `application.id` to scale out your application.

Comment: Thanks :) Another approach suggested by you was passing the stream through a dummy topic with many partitions to achieve scalability as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325678/is-scalability-applicalbe-with-kafka-stream-if-each-topic-has-single-partion. In case my custom stream partitioner splits  the stream into partitions based on hashcode value of a string, is there a possibility that the input stream with respective to a single partition might lose order when hitting the dummy topic?

Comment: for example: my input stream had 5 events belonging to a hashcode-107 in the order: 1,3,4,5,2 when passing through the dummy topic is there a chance that will be committed to the dummy topic as 1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: Depends: Order is preserved by key -- thus, if all records of a single topic do have the same key, yes, order will be preserved (it might be interleaved with records from other topics though). If you don't have any key, you could set the topic name as surrogate key before writing into the dummy topic to ensure that order is preserved.

Comment: "In general, the idea is that a StandbyTask cannot be assigned to a thread the runs the corresponding "active" task or a another copy of the same StandbyTasks: it does not increase fault-tolerance but only wastes memory as if a thread dies, all the task dies." Can you go deeper about this?

Comment: If a single thread (or actually instance) would maintain the active and corresponding standby task, and the instance dies, you lose both the active and standby at the same time. Thus, the standby would not provided increased fault-tolerance/availability. It would of course still use resources if assigned, but without any gain. Thus, instead of wasting resources for no gain, Kafka Streams just won't assign the standby if there is no capacity to not unnecessarily waste resources.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across such an issue, it might happen that the kafka stream is being closed (before it can go to RUNNING STATE) which hints streams API to invoke the close method, and the state changes from REBALANCING to PENDING_SHUTDOWN and then to NOT RUNNING.

This can occur if you are building your KafkaStreams in try-with-resources which automatically closes the stream after the try block is executed.