# Kafka stream change state without any reason

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm having a `KafkaStream` that at some point is moving the state from `REBALANCING` to `PENDING_ERROR`, but I never seen the reason why this happens.

I've implement an uncaught error handler, but it never invoked.

```
static StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler(final String streamIdentifier) {
    return th -> {
        logger.error("{} - Failed to catch exception in stream: {}", streamIdentifier, th.getMessage(), th);
        return StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler.StreamThreadExceptionResponse.REPLACE_THREAD;
    };
}
```

Also I have a listener for the change of state but it cannot give the reason.

```
static KafkaStreams.StateListener stateListener(final String streamIdentifier) {
    return (newState, oldState) -> logger.info("{} - Kafka Streams Correlation Changed State [{}] -> [{}]", streamIdentifier, oldState, newState);
}
```

Comment: Would [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47990643/6309) help?

Comment: You should inspect the logs.

Comment: No logs, but I think we have a problem there.  With version 3.3.1 works

Comment: Can you provide more context about the general configuration of your infrastructure? It sounds to me that the system is closing Kafka threads for some reason.